# Making a simple jQuery slideshow from scratch with a single forward/back control

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow, show-hide, carousel

I was really hoping some of you jQuery gurus could give me a hand on this one.

I have some markup that looks like so:

```
 <section id="carousel">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="dots">
        <li class="active">•</li>
        <li>•</li>
        <li>•</li>
      </ul>

      <button>Previous</button>
      <button>Next</button>
    </section>
```

I'd basically just like to loop infinitely between any number of divs using the previous/next buttons, AND move the .active class on the .dots to the corresponding li. Just not really sure how to go about it. I don't want to use a ready-made solution because A.) I'd like to keep the markup *just so* and B.) If one of you has a solution for me I'd like to reverse engineer it and expand the model to something a little more complex I have in mind.

Would really appreciate some examples if you guys have ideas. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: So you want us to write the code for you? Do you know jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

- To loop infinitely between the divs, you can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setInterval) to repeatedly call a function that changes the active div. Alternatively, you could use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) from within that function, making it recursive.
- To move the `.active` class around, you can use jQuery's [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) functions.
- To change the active `<div>` through the buttons, you can attach an event listener to them, such as `$("#before").click()` and `$("#after").click()`.

Comment: which fiddle are you talking about? I don't see one.